# How to write the set of freight ranges of the cost function from supplier to manufacturing in cplex code?

Tags: types

How to write the set of freight ranges of the cost function from supplier to manufacturing in cplex code ?

Number of units            Freight rate
1-21                        $422
22-62                       $/unit 13.2
63-134                      $/unit  10.8
135-312                     $/unit 8.7
313-654                     $/unit 7.0
655-1249                    $/unit 5.9
1250-1964                   $/unit 3.2
1965-2500                   $ 5533

I dont know the way to write this code

Answer (score 0):

You should use piecewise linear Function that are available with all Cplex apis

In opl for example

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoopiecewise.mod

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;

// If we take more than 4 buses for a given size, 20% cheaper for additional buses
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;

pwlFunction pricePerQuantity=piecewise{1->4;0.8};

assert forall(k in 1..4 ) pricePerQuantity(k)==k;
assert forall(k in 5..10) as:abs(pricePerQuantity(k)-4-(k-4)*0.8)<=0.00001;
 
minimize
 costBus40*pricePerQuantity(nbBus40)  +pricePerQuantity(nbBus30)*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```